# Vue JS -- Using v-sparkline with object list

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to have a simple sparkline in Vue JS. But i'm not sure how should i use label and value parameters in sparkline.
I want a graph showing how many users registered by years, so i have 2 field *"year"* and *"count"*. 
I can't get the year and count directly...

Sparkline;

```
<v-sparkline :value="countByYears.count" :labels="countByYears.year" color="rgba(255, 255, 255, .7)" height="100" padding="24" stroke-linecap="round" smooth>
</v-sparkline>
```

Data;

```
data: () => ({
  countByYears: [
     {year : 2020, count : 50},
     {year : 2019, count : 32},
     {year : 2018, count : 51},
     {year : 2017, count : 16}
  ],
})
```

Is there a way to get the year and count objects in the object list directly without calculating them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to compute two different arrays:

```
computed: {
 values() {
   return this.countForYears.map(x=>x.count);
 },
labels() {
  return this.countForYears.map(x=>x.year);
}
}

<v-sparkline :value="values" :labels="labels" color="rgba(255, 255, 255, .7)" height="100" padding="24" stroke-linecap="round" smooth>
</v-sparkline>
```

And use those for the values and labels props on the sparkline.

Full Example:

https://codepen.io/sbosell/pen/VwvrMPW?editors=1010